# Copy/paste data from Excel into website form

Tags: excel, applescript, automator

I need help correcting the script below to automate a very mundane copy/paste task that I have to do for the next few weeks with lists that will vary.

I have a reporting WIKI through our company site that lets us load in client `ID`s to run the report for that client `ID`. I have a list of 1,300 clients that I need to run this report for at varying weeks, and copy/pasting these client `ID`s (currently in an Excel worksheet) into the WIKI to run these reports.

CURRENT WORKFLOW:
Copy client ID from Excel, select the Chrome window and click into the text box, paste, click tab so that the WIKI displays the next textbox for me to add a client ID, go back to Excel copy and repeat... 1300 times...

I found the [following site](http://www.nextab.de/en/blog/copy-paste-automator-apple-script/) and tried to modify the code they had to work, but I am thinking the dictionaries have changed since then. I tried to look, but have not been able to figure it out.

```
repeat 2 times
tell application "/applications/Microsoft Excel.app" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Microsoft Excel"
        keystroke "c" using command down
    end tell
end tell
delay 0.3
tell application "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        keystroke "v" using command down
        keystroke tab
    end tell
end tell
delay 0.3

tell application "/applications/Microsoft Excel.app" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Microsoft Excel"
        keystroke return
        delay 0.4
        keystroke "c" using command down
        delay 0.3
    end tell
end tell
delay 0.3
tell application "/applications/Google Chrome.app" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        keystroke "v" using command down
        keystroke tab
    end tell
end tell
delay 0.3
end repeat
```

I have to run these reports monthly and do all the work to get these clients configured properly so that they have data in the WIKI.

Comment: Honestly tell the IT folks in your company to create a php interface to upload the data via HTTP

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you used the directory to the App when AppleScript just requires the Name, here :

```
repeat 2 times
tell application "Microsoft Excel" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Microsoft Excel"
        keystroke "c" using command down
    end tell
end tell
delay 0.3
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        keystroke "v" using command down
        keystroke tab
    end tell
end tell
delay 0.3

tell application "Microsoft Excel" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Microsoft Excel"
        keystroke return
        delay 0.4
        keystroke "c" using command down
        delay 0.3
    end tell
end tell
delay 0.3
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        keystroke "v" using command down
        keystroke tab
    end tell
end tell
delay 0.3
end repeat
```

Hope this helped!